# Setting up hostapd in Fedora 25/26

Tags: fedora, dnsmasq, hostapd

I am trying to setup a wireless access point on Fedora with Hostapd, because Hostapd has some extra features I need over the default hotspot functionality of the Gnome network manager.

I have added the following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, to make sure that the NetworkManager does not interfere with Hostapd.

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wl*
```

I have disabled the DNS-function from Dnsmasq, and set a range of DHCP addressess. My `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` looks like this:

```
port=0
interface=wlp3s0
dhcp-range=192.168.8.20,192.168.8.254,255.255.255.0,12h
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

In `etc/sysctl.conf` I added this line:

```
net.ip4.ip_forward=1
```

And then I have executed:

```
$ killall dnsmasq
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.8.0/24 ! -d 192.168.8.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
$ service NetworkManager restart
$ service dnsmasq start
$ service hostapd start
```

---

The problem is that other devices won't receive an ip-address when trying to connect to the access point. I am not sure how and where to find the problem.

I am asking this question, because there seem to be some differences with older versions and other distributions. For example, I don't have `wlan0` but `wlp3s0` and the `/etc/network/` folder does not exist in Fedora.

---

Okay, I had to enable DHPC with the firewall configuration, and now Dnsmasq keeps saying

```
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP packet received on wlp3s0 which has no address
```

---

And I have progressed one more step!

```
ifconfig wlp3s0 192.168.8.20/24 up
```

Now the devices can connect, but they don't have internet yet.